# Is Jitpack compatible with Gradle Kotlin?

Tags: java, gradle, jitpack

I've been trying my very hardest to get my code on jitpack but am having some issues, I fixed a handful of the initial errors I was getting but am unsure what to do about this one https://jitpack.io/com/github/CoolDCB/GardeningTweaks/fe2ce8646c/build.log

Publishing to maven local works perfectly from my pc and I believe I have done everything correctly
https://github.com/CoolDCB/GardeningTweaks/blob/main/build.gradle.kts

I was hoping that I would be able to get this working but am not too sure what else to try

Comment: Yes, it does work in general, as I'm using it for my own project. Perhaps you need to specify `openjdk17` in your jitpack.yml?

Comment: I've tried openjdk11 and openjdk17

Comment: If I try to build your project, it fails because the env variable which is required by this line is not set `System.getenv("pluginFolder_1-20")`.

Comment: Ooh that makes sense, I'll try commenting it out and see if that works at all

Comment: After commenting that out I am now getting a different error: https://jitpack.io/com/github/CoolDCB/GardeningTweaks/6c1aae9976/build.log

Comment: It seems like I've got it working but am not entirely sure what fixed it

Comment: Hello, @Dave . Did you fix it ? I'm on the same issue now and found this thread.

Comment: @Dave please tell us your fix!